# Install mod_pagespeed under nginx on gentoo

Tags: linux, nginx, gentoo, mod-pagespeed

I want to install mod_pagespeen under gentoo using emerge.
i added NGINX_ADD_MODULES="/root/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta" in make.conf.

When i try to compile nginx via emerge (emerge -D nginx) i receive the following message:

```
adding module in /root/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta
./configure: error: no /root/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta/config was found

ERROR: www-servers/nginx-1.4.4::gentoo failed (configure phase):
configure failed *
Call stack:
ebuild.sh, line 93: Called src_configure
environment, line 3640: Called die
The specific snippet of code:
./configure --prefix="${EPREFIX}"/usr --conf-path="${EPREFIX}"/etc/${PN}/${PN}.conf --error-log-path="${EPREFIX}"/var/log/${PN}/error_log --pid-path="${EPREFIX}"/run/${PN}.pid --lock-path="${EPREFIX}"/run/lock/${PN}.lock --with-cc-opt="-I${EROOT}usr/include" --with-ld-opt="-L${EROOT}usr/lib" --http-log-path="${EPREFIX}"/var/log/${PN}/access_log --http-client-body-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/client --http-proxy-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/fastcgi --http-scgi-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/uwsgi ${myconf} || die "configure failed";
the folder /root/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta/ exists on my compter:

dev ~ # ls -alh /root/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta/
total 89M
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K Dec 18 22:07 .
drwx------ 14 root root 4.0K Dec 18 22:44 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30 Nov 8 18:36 .gitignore
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 89M Nov 7 21:00 1.7.30.1.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12K Nov 8 18:36 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4.8K Nov 8 18:36 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 8.0K Nov 8 18:36 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.9K Nov 8 18:36 cpp_feature
drwxr-x--- 4 182960 5000 4.0K Nov 7 15:59 psol
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 8 18:36 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 8 18:36 src
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 8 18:36 test
```

As you can see the file (/root/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta/config) is there but i still receive the error message.

Can you please help me?

For the first answer. Thanks for your help!
I moved ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta to /opt and changed permissions on it to portage:portage. The result is the same:

```
adding module in /opt/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta ./configure: error: no /opt/ngx_pagespeed-1.7.30.1-beta/config was found * ERROR: www-servers/nginx-1.4.4::gentoo failed (configure phase): * configure failed * * Call stack: * ebuild.sh, line 93: Called src_configure * environment, line 3640: Called die * The specific snippet of code: * ./configure --prefix="${EPREFIX}"/usr --conf-path="${EPREFIX}"/etc/${PN}/${PN}.conf --error-log-path="${EPREFIX}"/var/log/${PN}/error_log --pid-path="${EPREFIX}"/run/${PN}.pid --lock-path="${EPREFIX}"/run/lock/${PN}.lock --with-cc-opt="-I${EROOT}usr/include" --with-ld-opt="-L${EROOT}usr/lib" --http-log-path="${EPREFIX}"/var/log/${PN}/access_log --http-client-body-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/client --http-proxy-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/proxy --http-fastcgi-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/fastcgi --http-scgi-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path="${EPREFIX}/${NGINX_HOME_TMP}"/uwsgi ${myconf} || die "configure failed";
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a permissions issue. You may have the userpriv Portage FEATURE enabled, which means that packages will not be built as root. Move the directory somewhere world-readable.